# Why is Google Chrome making these weird requests?

Tags: google-chrome

I noticed that now and again, Chrome will make three requests to weird hostnames that arent resolved. For example:

```
HEAD http://gtblynlsos/ HTTP/1.1
Host: gtblynlsos
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.107 Safari/534.13
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Other example weird hostnames:

```
http://nxibbjklov/
http://moheksgryj/
```

Has anyone else seen this? Any ideas what's going on? I have all Chrome extensions disabled.

**UPDATE**
This question answered already on serverfault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/235307/unusual-head-requests-to-nonsense-urls-from-chrome

Comment: @Joset: This is better as an answer.

Comment: Chrome is 'infected', with what?

Comment: Ahah, never mind. The professionals know what's up http://serverfault.com/questions/235307/unusual-head-requests-to-nonsense-urls-from-chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question answered already on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/235307/unusual-head-requests-to-nonsense-urls-from-chrome